# How to change views when I click a button?

Tags: extjs, view, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, push

I'm using, or abusing, Sencha Touch for the first time and I just want to push a list view, when i click a button.  Here is my view:

```
Ext.define('TouchNuts.view.Decision', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'decision',

config: {
    title: 'Decision',

    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    styleHtmlCls: 'Decision',
    tpl: '<h2>{name}</h2>, <h3>{description}<h3>, <h4>{price:ellipsis(15)}</h4> <h1>you can do this </h1>',



        items: [

                        {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'SEND',
                        ui: 'confirm',
                        docked: 'bottom',
                        action:  'doSomething'
                        }
               ]
         }
 });
```

Here is the view I'd like to push:

```
Ext.define('TouchNuts.view.File', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'file',

config: {
    title: 'File',
    iconCls: 'star',
    layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                        xtype: 'list',
                        id: 'file',
                        store: 'TransactionStore',
                        itemTpl: '<h2>{name:ellipsis(15)}</h2>, <h3>{description:ellipsis(8)}<h3>, <h4>{price:ellipsis(15)}</h4>',
                        itemCls: 'SummaryItems'
                }
            ]
    }
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
Ext.define('TouchNuts.controller.doSomething', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {

    },
        control: {
          'button[action=doSomething]' : {
             tap: function() {
               getMainView('TouchNuts.view.Decision').push('TouchNuts.view.File');

             }
         }

}
}
});
```

I'm pretty good with HTML, CSS, and jQuery, but new to JS and totally clueless when it comes to Sencha so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to give your views an itemId inorder to reference them in your controller. So for instance:

`TouchNuts.view.Decision` can have an itemId:`decisionPanel`

and

`TouchNuts.view.File` can have an itemId:`filePanel`

Now in your `Controller` you would do this:

```
...
config: {
    refs: {
       decisionPanel: {
           autocreate: true,
           selector: '#decisionPanel',
           xtype: 'decision'
       },    
       filePanel: {
           autocreate: true,
           selector: '#filePanel',
           xtype: 'file'               
       }
    },
    control: {
      'button[action=doSomething]' : {
         tap: 'onButtonTap'
     }

}

onButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(me.getDecisionPanel());
}
...
```

You will notice that I used `getDecisionPanel()` to get the `decisionPanel` view. This is because  a getter function is automatically generated for each `ref` you specify and in order to access it, you new to use `get`+ the Capitalized `ref` name.
More info here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Comment: A itemId is a known identifier within one component level. And it need only to be valid within the component level. On component level there is a extra getter for itemId's. But you are using the query selector for id's where it is recommend to let the framework set them. You are talking about one thing but using another. -1 You should fix your answer and I will remove my Downvote

Comment: If someone comment a downvote and give you in that way a chance to improve or correct your answer it is not that usefull to start giving uncommented down ores to that user.

Comment: @sra I've updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback. I've tested the above code and it works.

Comment: Very well, then I will remove my downvote as soon as you either commented why you down voted my answers or you removes the downvote.

Comment: @sra I never down voted your answer. I actually up voted your comment above.

Comment: If so I take it all back and shame on me. And actually I inverted my downvote. But you know, it was a bit curious that I got two downvotes the same time you lose to unlisted points...

Comment: I tried this code, but I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined `  Any idea why?

Comment: What's a scope issue?  `TouchNuts.view.Decision` is already within another container: `'TouchNuts.view.TransactionsContainer'`  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
getMainView('TouchNuts.view.Decision').push('TouchNuts.view.File');
```

You have to create the view first and then push it to view

```
getMainView('TouchNuts.view.Decision').push(Ext.create('TouchNuts.view.File'));
```